# Count data written in last 15 min to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, command-line-interface, cql, hector

In Cassandra each written column has a timestamp which can be accessed using the getClock() method (once pooled from the DB).

I would like to know how many columns got written in the last X minutes (let's say 15 minutes) to Cassandra.
I looked at the [secondary index pattern](http://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/cassandra-secondary-index-patterns/) but could not find it usable for my needs.

Is there a way of doing that (I don't mind which client - CQL, CLI, Hector etc').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra exposes a lot of metrics about itself, including request counts and latencies as JMX beans. Run JConsole against one of your Cassandra nodes and find `org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamily`. Below it in the tree there will be nodes for each table, within each keyspace. Pick the `WriteLatency` MBean and look at it's attributes; the `FifteenMinuteRate` is the number of write requests per second on average over the last 15 minutes. `Count` is the total number of write requests.

Comment: Following your answer I read this: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/cassandra/operations/ops_monitoring_c.html and eventually decided to user the nodetool utility ( http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/cassandra/tools/toolsNodetool_r.html ) which helped me alot. These metrics did not answer my question directly but they help understand the picture. Thanks :)